Encoding error when pulling data from Oracle DB
When I am pulling data from Oracle DB, I am getting error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: invalid start byte
I tried setting encoding in nencoding to 'utf-16' and 'windows-1252' in the connect function like:
oracledb.connect(user=user, password=userpwd, dsn="dbhost.example.com/orclpdb", 
    encoding='windows-1252', nencoding='windows-1252')

but I am still getting the same error.

From knowing the code, nencoding has nothing to do with this this, and is totally ignored in python-oracledb.  encoding is similarly ignored - read the doc.  More usefully read the doc Querying Corrupt Data.  If you still have issues, ask on GitHub and post full details such as version numbers of all components.
